# How to connect to Impala when running Hadoop Cluster with Edge Nodes

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, gateway

I have installed Hadoop cluster using Cloudera Manager, and currently Impala Daemon is running on all the data nodes. Cluster is behind the Gateway/Edge nodes, and only gateway services are installed on the Edge Node (e.g httpfs, hive gateway, spark gateway, oozie).

I am wondering, how I can connect Impala from using Gateway/Edge node, as all the impala daemons are running on Cluster's Data nodes, and no service is exposed to Gateway/Edge node.

Comment: You can install impala CLI on the edge node  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_install.html

Comment: The problem is not Impala CLI, I already have Impala CLI on edge node. Problem is my hadoop cluster is behind the edge node, so to get anything executed on my hadoop cluster, I have to connect to one of impala daemon running on data nodes, which I won't be able to connect from outside. I am going to try HA approach suggested by facha.

Comment: Er... Note that in "HAProxy", the important part is **proxy**, not HA... Because that proxy will become, *de facto*, a SPOF. So much for High Availability.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I was just looking for the proxy service, which can redirect my traffic to one of the impala daemons running within cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install haproxy on your edge node:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/impala_proxy.html